# Is there a general directly executable type for Objective-C blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I’d like to get rid of the complex type declaration before my one-shot blocks:

```
void (^blockHelperA)(NSString*, NSString*) = ^(NSString *foo, NSString *bar) {…};
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
id blockHelperB = ^(NSString *foo, NSString *bar) {…};
```

Which looks better and compiles, but can’t be directly executed:

```
// “Called object type 'id' is not a function or function pointer”
blockHelperB(@"Foo", @"Bar");
```

Then there’s a `dispatch_block_t` type, but that’s just a simple shorthand:

```
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
```

Is there a way to get rid of the precise type declaration and still execute the block afterwards in a simple way? I know I can do this:

```
id foo = ^{ return @"bar"; };
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_current_queue(), foo);
```

…but that just shifts the noise from the declaration to execution.

Comment: I found [this article](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/) about blocks which is very interesting.

Comment: That’s a great resource about blocks (I have already read it before), but it does not answer my question, at least if I didn’t miss something.

Comment: The only way to do this is to break the type system and hope nothing bad happens. Specifically, you can declare a block which takes an unknown number of arguments, but the only calling convention in which that makes sense is cdecl. And the calling convention used by a block may or not be cdecl. Clang appears to let you set this in the declaration, gcc apparently does not.

Just typedef and be done with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no (*sane*) way to do this as you are restricted by C's type system.

For function pointers and blocks in particular, C will not allow you to define a "generic" type.

An example of this is that the type `dispatch_block_t` will **only** work with blocks that have a void return type and zero arguments. ***No other block signature will work. Period.***

Since blocks are effectively transformed into function pointers at compile time (among other magic), there is no direct type associated with them. Your mileage may vary greatly as to the actual type of block that you have stored in any given block reference. So, with this in mind, you can understand why the compiler doesn't understand you when you try to store a block in an `id`.

More information on this can be found here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html.

Sorry, but this is just one of those quirks that you will have to learn to live with.

Comment: In particular, the compiler needs to generate code that sets up the call stack, and potentially memory for the return value depending on the return type.